# How can I add dates to dataframe which only displays once for multiple instances?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a [website](https://sport-tv-guide.live/tv-guide-live/movistar-deportes) to return what events are taking place on a channel. I'm having difficulty adding the dates to the event because of how they're stored - once for all the events on the day under a `dateSeparator` class.

I imagine I will have to count all the events between each event then apply the date to those, the problem is I have no clue how to achieve that. Can someone lend me a hand, please?

**My code**

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

class STG:
    url = "https://sport-tv-guide.live/"
    channel = (f"{url}/tv-guide-live/movistar-deportes")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(f"{STG.channel}")
html = driver.page_source
soup  = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")

teams = [x.text.strip() for x in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'col-inline'})]
times = [x.text.strip() for x in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'main time col-sm-2 hidden-xs'})]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(times, teams)), columns = ['sport', 'teams'])

df[["sport", "time"]] = df.sport.str.split("\n", expand=True)
df[["teams", "comp"]] = df.teams.str.split("\n", expand=True)
df[["ht", "at"]] = df.teams.str.split(" - ", expand=True)

print(df)

driver.quit()
```

**HTML sample** - [full link](https://sport-tv-guide.live/tv-guide-live/movistar-deportes)

```html
<div class="listData">  
                    <div class="ajax-load text-center" style="display: none;"><p><img data-src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/loading.gif" height="40px" class="lazyload"></p></div>  
                <div class="dateSeparator">
                             <span class="date"> 1 Jan</span>
                             <div class="dateCenter">Tomorrow</div>
                           </div>
 <a class="article" href="/event/live-tennis-atp-cup-teams-serbia-norway/797348?id=3640101073016">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="main col-xs-2 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg pl-0  text-center">
             <div class="font-size-10"><img data-src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/t8.png" class="w-40 lazyloaded" title="Tennis" src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/t8.png"></div>
             06:30           </div>
           <div class="main time col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
             <div class="typeName col-wrap">Tennis</div>
             <b>06:30</b>
             
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-10">
              <div class="clearfix">
                  <img id="img-inline" class="pr-5 hidden-xs hidden-xxs lazyloaded" data-src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/leaguem-atp-cup-teams-2765.png" height="40" width="40" title="ATP Cup Teams" src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/leaguem-atp-cup-teams-2765.png">                  <div class="col-inline">
                    <div class="text-nowrap">Serbia - Norway</div>
                    <div class="text-nowrap"><b>ATP Cup Teams</b></div>
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-wrap text-right" id="ev3640101073016"></div>
        </div>
</a>   

 <a class="article" href="/event/live-tennis-atp-cup-teams-serbia-norway/797348?id=3640101093016">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="main col-xs-2 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg pl-0  text-center">
             <div class="font-size-10"><img data-src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/t8.png" class="w-40 lazyloaded" title="Tennis" src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/t8.png"></div>
             08:30           </div>
           <div class="main time col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
             <div class="typeName col-wrap">Tennis</div>
             <b>08:30</b>
             
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-10">
              <div class="clearfix">
                  <img id="img-inline" class="pr-5 hidden-xs hidden-xxs lazyloaded" data-src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/leaguem-atp-cup-teams-2765.png" height="40" width="40" title="ATP Cup Teams" src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/leaguem-atp-cup-teams-2765.png">                  <div class="col-inline">
                    <div class="text-nowrap">Serbia - Norway</div>
                    <div class="text-nowrap"><b>ATP Cup Teams</b></div>
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-wrap text-right" id="ev3640101093016"></div>
        </div>
</a>   

 <a class="article" href="/event/live-tennis-atp-cup-teams-serbia-norway/797348?id=3640101113016">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="main col-xs-2 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg pl-0  text-center">
             <div class="font-size-10"><img data-src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/t8.png" class="w-40 lazyloaded" title="Tennis" src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/t8.png"></div>
             10:30           </div>
           <div class="main time col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
             <div class="typeName col-wrap">Tennis</div>
             <b>10:30</b>
             
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-10">
              <div class="clearfix">
                  <img id="img-inline" class="pr-5 hidden-xs hidden-xxs lazyloaded" data-src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/leaguem-atp-cup-teams-2765.png" height="40" width="40" title="ATP Cup Teams" src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/leaguem-atp-cup-teams-2765.png">                  <div class="col-inline">
                    <div class="text-nowrap">Serbia - Norway</div>
                    <div class="text-nowrap"><b>ATP Cup Teams</b></div>
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-wrap text-right" id="ev3640101113016"></div>
        </div>
</a>   

 <a class="article" href="/event/live-tennis-atp-cup-teams-russia-france/797350?id=3640101000016">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="main col-xs-2 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg pl-0  text-center">
             <div class="font-size-10"><img data-src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/t8.png" class="w-40 lazyloaded" title="Tennis" src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/t8.png"></div>
             23:00           </div>
           <div class="main time col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
             <div class="typeName col-wrap">Tennis</div>
             <b>23:00</b>
             
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-10">
              <div class="clearfix">
                  <img id="img-inline" class="pr-5 hidden-xs hidden-xxs lazyloaded" data-src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/leaguem-atp-cup-teams-2765.png" height="40" width="40" title="ATP Cup Teams" src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/leaguem-atp-cup-teams-2765.png">                  <div class="col-inline">
                    <div class="text-nowrap">Russia - France</div>
                    <div class="text-nowrap"><b>ATP Cup Teams</b></div>
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-wrap text-right" id="ev3640101000016"></div>
        </div>
</a>   
<div class="dateSeparator">
                             <span class="date"> 2 Jan</span>
                             <div class="dateCenter">Sunday</div>
                           </div>
 <a class="article" href="/event/live-tennis-atp-cup-teams-russia-france/797350?id=3640101020016">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="main col-xs-2 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg pl-0  text-center">
             <div class="font-size-10"><img data-src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/t8.png" class="w-40 lazyloaded" title="Tennis" src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/t8.png"></div>
             01:00           </div>
           <div class="main time col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
             <div class="typeName col-wrap">Tennis</div>
             <b>01:00</b>
             
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-10">
              <div class="clearfix">
                  <img id="img-inline" class="pr-5 hidden-xs hidden-xxs lazyloaded" data-src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/leaguem-atp-cup-teams-2765.png" height="40" width="40" title="ATP Cup Teams" src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/leaguem-atp-cup-teams-2765.png">                  <div class="col-inline">
                    <div class="text-nowrap">Russia - France</div>
                    <div class="text-nowrap"><b>ATP Cup Teams</b></div>
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-wrap text-right" id="ev3640101020016"></div>
        </div>
</a>   

 <a class="article" href="/event/live-tennis-atp-cup-teams-russia-france/797350?id=3640101041516">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="main col-xs-2 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg pl-0  text-center">
             <div class="font-size-10"><img data-src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/t8.png" class="w-40 lazyloaded" title="Tennis" src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/t8.png"></div>
             03:15           </div>
           <div class="main time col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
             <div class="typeName col-wrap">Tennis</div>
             <b>03:15</b>
             
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-10">
              <div class="clearfix">
                  <img id="img-inline" class="pr-5 hidden-xs hidden-xxs lazyloaded" data-src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/leaguem-atp-cup-teams-2765.png" height="40" width="40" title="ATP Cup Teams" src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/leaguem-atp-cup-teams-2765.png">                  <div class="col-inline">
                    <div class="text-nowrap">Russia - France</div>
                    <div class="text-nowrap"><b>ATP Cup Teams</b></div>
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-wrap text-right" id="ev3640101041516"></div>
        </div>
</a>   

 <a class="article" href="/event/live-tennis-atp-cup-teams-germany-greatbritain/797351?id=3640102073016">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="main col-xs-2 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg pl-0  text-center">
             <div class="font-size-10"><img data-src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/t8.png" class="w-40 lazyloaded" title="Tennis" src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/t8.png"></div>
             06:30           </div>
           <div class="main time col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
             <div class="typeName col-wrap">Tennis</div>
             <b>06:30</b>
             
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-10">
              <div class="clearfix">
                  <img id="img-inline" class="pr-5 hidden-xs hidden-xxs lazyloaded" data-src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/leaguem-atp-cup-teams-2765.png" height="40" width="40" title="ATP Cup Teams" src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/leaguem-atp-cup-teams-2765.png">                  <div class="col-inline">
                    <div class="text-nowrap">Germany - Great Britain</div>
                    <div class="text-nowrap"><b>ATP Cup Teams</b></div>
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-wrap text-right" id="ev3640102073016"></div>
        </div>
</a>   

 <a class="article" href="/event/live-tennis-atp-cup-teams-germany-greatbritain/797351?id=3640102093016">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="main col-xs-2 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg pl-0  text-center">
             <div class="font-size-10"><img data-src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/t8.png" class="w-40 lazyloaded" title="Tennis" src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/t8.png"></div>
             08:30           </div>
           <div class="main time col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
             <div class="typeName col-wrap">Tennis</div>
             <b>08:30</b>
             
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-10">
              <div class="clearfix">
                  <img id="img-inline" class="pr-5 hidden-xs hidden-xxs lazyloaded" data-src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/leaguem-atp-cup-teams-2765.png" height="40" width="40" title="ATP Cup Teams" src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/leaguem-atp-cup-teams-2765.png">                  <div class="col-inline">
                    <div class="text-nowrap">Germany - Great Britain</div>
                    <div class="text-nowrap"><b>ATP Cup Teams</b></div>
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-wrap text-right" id="ev3640102093016"></div>
        </div>
</a>   

 <a class="article" href="/event/live-tennis-atp-cup-teams-germany-greatbritain/797351?id=3640102113016">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="main col-xs-2 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg pl-0  text-center">
             <div class="font-size-10"><img data-src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/t8.png" class="w-40 lazyloaded" title="Tennis" src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/t8.png"></div>
             10:30           </div>
           <div class="main time col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
             <div class="typeName col-wrap">Tennis</div>
             <b>10:30</b>
             
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-10">
              <div class="clearfix">
                  <img id="img-inline" class="pr-5 hidden-xs hidden-xxs ls-is-cached lazyloaded" data-src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/leaguem-atp-cup-teams-2765.png" height="40" width="40" title="ATP Cup Teams" src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/leaguem-atp-cup-teams-2765.png">                  <div class="col-inline">
                    <div class="text-nowrap">Germany - Great Britain</div>
                    <div class="text-nowrap"><b>ATP Cup Teams</b></div>
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-wrap text-right" id="ev3640102113016"></div>
        </div>
</a>   

 <a class="article" href="/event/live-basketball-acb?uid=3640102175516">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="main col-xs-2 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg pl-0  text-center">
             <div class="font-size-10"><img data-src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/t5.png" class="w-40 ls-is-cached lazyloaded" title="Basketball" src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/t5.png"></div>
             16:55           </div>
           <div class="main time col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
             <div class="typeName col-wrap">Basketball</div>
             <b>16:55</b>
             
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-10">
              <div class="clearfix">
                  <img id="img-inline" class="pr-5 hidden-xs hidden-xxs lazyloaded" data-src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/leaguem-acb-30.png" height="40" width="40" title="ACB" src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/leaguem-acb-30.png">                  <div class="col-inline">
                    <div class="text-nowrap">Liga Endesa (T21/22): Unicaja - Casademont Zaragoza</div>
                    <div class="text-nowrap"></div>
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-wrap text-right" id="ev3640102175516"></div>
        </div>
</a>   

 <a class="article" href="/event/live-basketball-nba-torontoraptors-newyorkknicks/789250?id=3640102213016">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="main col-xs-2 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg pl-0  text-center">
             <div class="font-size-10"><img data-src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/t5.png" class="w-40 ls-is-cached lazyloaded" title="Basketball" src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/t5.png"></div>
             20:30           </div>
           <div class="main time col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
             <div class="typeName col-wrap">Basketball</div>
             <b>20:30</b>
             
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-10">
              <div class="clearfix">
                  <img id="img-inline" class="pr-5 hidden-xs hidden-xxs lazyloaded" data-src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/leaguem-nba-26.png" height="40" width="40" title="NBA" src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/leaguem-nba-26.png">                  <div class="col-inline">
                    <div class="text-nowrap">Toronto Raptors - New York Knicks</div>
                    <div class="text-nowrap"><b>NBA</b></div>
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-wrap text-right" id="ev3640102213016"></div>
        </div>
</a>   
<div class="dateSeparator">
                             <span class="date"> 3 Jan</span>
                             <div class="dateCenter">Monday</div>
                           </div>
 <a class="article" href="/event/live-am-football-nfl-minnesotavikings-greenbaypackers/779303?id=3640102022016">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="main col-xs-2 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg pl-0  text-center">
             <div class="font-size-10"><img data-src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/t22.png" class="w-40 ls-is-cached lazyloaded" title="Am. Football" src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/t22.png"></div>
             01:20           </div>
           <div class="main time col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
             <div class="typeName col-wrap">Am. Football</div>
             <b>01:20</b>
             
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-10">
              <div class="clearfix">
                  <img id="img-inline" class="pr-5 hidden-xs hidden-xxs lazyloaded" data-src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/leaguem-nfl-40.png" height="40" width="40" title="NFL" src="https://img.sport-tv-guide.live/images/leaguem-nfl-40.png">                  <div class="col-inline">
                    <div class="text-nowrap">Minnesota Vikings - Green Bay Packers</div>
                    <div class="text-nowrap"><b>NFL</b></div>
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-wrap text-right" id="ev3640102022016"></div>
        </div>

</a>   
</div>
```

[image: Example of website date formatting]

[image: Expected output, adding a date column like column B.]

Comment: can you share an example of your excepted output?

Comment: Sure @TomerS, I've added a spreadsheet screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve, basically adding in column B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to achieve?

Change the approach of collecting your data a bit and select the elements in order they appear under the date seperators.

**Step #1**

Select all the date seperators:

```
soup.select('.dateSeparator')
```

**Step #2**

Iterate over each of them and all of its next siblings and break if the sibling is an `<div>`:

```
for item in date.find_next_siblings():
    if item.name == 'div':
        break
```

**Step #3**

Extract the texts with `stripped_strings` and make some adjustments, cause the structure is not always the same:

```
text = tuple(item.stripped_strings)
...
```

**Step #4**

Store the infromation in a list of dicts and create your dataframe.

```
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

#### Example

**Note:** *The output may be slightly different from the expected one, as I created it before you added the screenshot and I was shown the German website. However, the direction should be clear and the approach is to be adapted.*

```
...
data = []
for date in soup.select('.dateSeparator'):
    
    for item in date.find_next_siblings():
        if item.name == 'div':
            break

        text = tuple(item.stripped_strings)
        data.append({
            'date':date.span.text.strip(),
            'time':text[0],
            'sport':text[1],
            'at':text[3].split('-')[-1] if len(text) > 4 else text[3].split(':')[-1].split('-')[-1],
            'teams':text[3] if len(text) > 4 else text[3].split(':')[-1],
            'event':text[4] if len(text) > 4 else text[3].split(':')[0] 
        })

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

#### Output

| date | time | sport | at | teams | event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Jan | 07:30 | Tennis | Norwegen | Serbien - Norwegen | ATP-Cup-Teams |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 3 Jan | 21:30 | Basketball | Breogan | Obradoiro CAB - Breogan | ACB |

Comment: Thank you for the very comprehensive answer, I'll follow your advice on how data is collected, for sure. This almost works directly inputting it into my code except it is duplicating the events on every day, rather than the date they are to be played on. I will try and resolve it myself.

Comment: I'll mark it as correct as soon as I tweak it to appear just how I need it, but you've definitely put me on the right path. I've voted it up for usefullness. Thanks.

Comment: I've been toying with the code for a while now, but I'm not having any luck producing the result I'm looking for. As you can see I'm hoping to return 19 rows, but the result is 42 rows, the events on the later dates (2 Jan, 3 Jan) are being duplicated and triplicated in the case of the 3 Jan events. Any idea how that can be solved?

Comment: @SpingoTakagi : Well, good point. Missed to check if there is the next `div` with `.dateSeparator` --> Take a look at Step #2, I also updated the example. Sorry for the inattention on my part to check it twice.